# DefinitelyTyped @types and lean imports

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

If my project includes **@types/braintree-web** and I

```js
import braintree from 'braintree-web'

const client = braintree.client
```

then **client** is properly typed as braintree.Client.

However, I want to use lean imports like:

```js
import braintreeClient from 'braintree-web/client/index.js'
```

and I want braintreeClient to also be typed as braintree.Client. Instead, I get TypeScript warnings:

```
Could not find a declaration file for 'braintree-web/client/index.js'
```

Was thinking I would add this to my global.d.ts...

```js
/// <reference types="braintree-web" />

declare module 'braintree-web/client/index.js' {
  
}
```

Is there a way where I can reuse the typings that were already defined for 'braintree' rather than recreate them for each lean import?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { braintreeClient } from 'braintree-web'
```

Or this may work as well

```
import * as braintreeClient = from 'braintree-web/client'
```

Comment: Would this still support tree-shaking as 'braintree-web' is CommonJS?